# Azure Storage - Download a blob with conditions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I've been having trouble assigning read conditions on blobs when trying to download them when using the [Azure Storage SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage).

Basically, what I am trying to do goes like this:

1. Upload a blob (**WORKS**)
2. Download the blob (**WORKS**)
3. Get the Etag of the blob with `blobRef.GetProperties().Etag` (**WORKS**)
4. Use the Etag to try to download the blob again expecting a `RequestFailedException e` where the `e.ErrorCode == ConditionNotMet` (**FAILS**)

This is the code:

```
var condition = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobRequestConditions
{
    IfNoneMatch = new Azure.ETag(previousEtagString),
};

//blobRef is a valid instance of Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient
//target is the filePath

blobRef.DownloadTo(target, conditions: condition); // this should throw RequestFailedException
```

**Notes:**

1. When I try to compare the Etag fetched from step 3 (which is converted to a string) with the one I am sending in step 4, it returns they are the same  `blobRef.GetProperties().Etag == new Azure.Etag(blobRef.GetProperties().Etag.ToString())` -> `true`
2. I also [opened](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/30710) the question at the GitHub Repo
3. Passing test cases with v11:

   ```
   var blobRef = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(identifier);
   blobRef.DownloadTo(target, AccessCondition.GenerateIfNoneMatchCondition(stringEtag)); //throws StorageException
   ```
4. Just noticed that the blob downloaded the second time, does not contain any data. It's empty. The first one has data. Are the read conditions partially working, but not throwing the exception?
5. This is definitely a bug. I [opened the issue in the Github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/30724)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Use the Etag to try to download the blob again expecting a
> RequestFailedException e where the e.ErrorCode == ConditionNotMet

This is not the expected behavior because Etag only changes when a blob is updated.

If a blob is not updated, Etag value remains the same. So if you do not update the blob, you can perform a conditional download multiple times without getting the precondition failure error.

Comment: This was not the case in version 11. Is this the new behavior with v12?

Comment: Nope. It has been like this forever. Etag is a server-side thing and has nothing to do with the client SDKs.

Comment: Weird. We have testcases that were using the older version which took the `CloudBlockBlob` and called `OpenRead()` with `AccessCondition.GenerateIfNoneMatchCondition(eTag)` and would throw `StorageException`

Comment: Will it be possible to share the code for the failed test using previous version?

Comment: Sure, but there's no much to show. Please, see my updates.

Comment: Just noticed that the file that is downloaded with the condition contains no data. It's like the read condition is partially working, but not throwing the exception.

Comment: Hey, in case you still are interested on this. I opened a bug ticket. Since the SDK is just an API wrapper, I think the problem comes directly from Azure's API. I added a code sample for you to see.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/30724